# NodeJs Using ExpressJs : TypeError: string is not a function at Function.app.render

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I just started learning Node and I am trying to build a web application using Node and Express. And I have the following code in my *app.js* file, with the following directory structure.

**Directory Structure:**

```
app
   assets
   controller
   model
   view
      index.jade
global
node_modules
app.js
package.json
```

**-js-**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.configure(function() {
  app.set('view', __dirname + '/app/view');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(app.router);
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index', {title: 'express'});
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Listening on port 3000');
```

After running the command `node app` and going to localhost:3000. I get the following error. I am assuming it doesn't like the string on this line -> `res.render('index', {title: 'express'});`. However from everything I have found on Google this seems right. So I must be missing something else.

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

TypeError: string is not a function at Function.app.render (C:\myapp\express\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:488:12) at ServerResponse.res.render (C:\myapp\express\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:803:7) at C:\myapp\express\app.js:19:6 at callbacks (C:\myapp\express\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:164:37) at param (C:\myapp\express\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:138:11) at pass (C:\myapp\express\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:145:5) at Router._dispatch (C:\myapp\express\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:173:5) at Object.router (C:\myapp\express\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:33:10) at next (C:\myapp\express\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:190:15) at Object.expressInit [as handle] (C:\myapp\express\node_modules\express\lib\middleware.js:30:5)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think this is just a typo/mistake setting 'view' (singular) instead of 'views' (plural). Check out this example. I think the express application object has both 'view' and 'views' settings but they mean different things.

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/jade/index.js

Here's your fix to be clear:

```
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/app/view');
```

Comment: Yep, that seems to be the issue. Of course now I have a new erorr for indentation. But I can fix that. I was under the assumption that `views` was to match my directory name. Guess I was wrong. Anyways thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah TJ is a master of naming that is initially extremely confusing but is concise once you from it. `app.get`, `app.use`, `app.configure` throw noobs for a loop. This one should just be `app.set('viewPath')` IMHO. Also you can remove your `app.configure` wrapper as it is accomplishing precisely jack squat.